# Meaning Esri product life cycle support

Tags: arcgis, esri

Dose any one knows the meaning of these terms in Esri ArcGIS Product life cycle?

General Availability?
Extended Support?
Mature Support?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

A quick Google search finds Esri Product Lifecycle Support Policy (https://downloads2.esri.com/support/TechArticles/Product-Life-Cycle.pdf ).  Since the definition of those terms depends on the product line, I will not post any excerpts since you didn't state the products you are using.